# How to detect the country and city of a user accessing your site?

Tags: python, web-applications

How can you detect the country of origin of the users accessing your site?

I'm using Google Analytics on my site and can see that I have users coming from different regions of the world.

But within my application I would like to provide some additional customization based on the country and perhaps the city.

Is it possible to detect this infomation from the browser? This is a Python web application.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Grab and gunzip http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz, install the GeoIP-Python package (python-geoip package if you're in Debian or Ubuntu, otherwise install http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/python/GeoIP-Python-1.2.4.tar.gz), and do:

```
import GeoIP
gi = GeoIP.open("GeoLiteCity.dat", GeoIP.GEOIP_INDEX_CACHE | GeoIP.GEOIP_CHECK_CACHE)
print gi.record_by_name("74.125.67.100") # a www.google.com IP
```

`{'city': 'Mountain View', 'region_name': 'California', 'region': 'CA', 'area_code': 650, 'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles', 'longitude': -122.05740356445312, 'country_code3': 'USA', 'latitude': 37.419200897216797, 'postal_code': '94043', 'dma_code': 807, 'country_code': 'US', 'country_name': 'United States'}`

The database is free (http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/LICENSE.txt).  They do sell it, too; I think that just gets you more frequent updates.

Comment: By the way, there's also a country-only database that's much smaller, if that's all you need (http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz).  Just change the file over, use GeoIP.GEOIP_STANDARD instead of the flags above, and then call gi.country_code_by_name(ip).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I've used the maxmind web interface but never noticed that they offer a free database before.

Comment: Just FYI, MaxMind Precision is remarkably more accurate than GeoLite, if you want to have better accuracy than just countries. For countries, there's virtually no differences (in my dataset, 400 address-location pairs from 85 countries). I recently studied this  as part of my Master's thesis (not done yet so won't link to it now).

Comment: @GlennMaynard Is it possible to convert to other language, such as Chinese?

Answer (score 8):

Get the visitor's IP and check it with a [geolocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation) web service (or purchase a geolocation database if you're keen to host that determination in-house).

Answer (score 1):

Max mind costs money.
For a free yet country code only solution you can try:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geoip2nation/

pip install geoip2nation

```
from geoip import geoip
r = geoip.GeoIp()
r.load_memory()
r.resolve("12.12.12.12").country_code
#This prints : 'US'

print r.resolve("123.44.57.4")
#This prints : {'country': 'Korea (South)', 'host_name': '', 'country_code': 'KR'}

r.resolve2("12.12.12.12")
#This prints : 'US'
```

Comment: It is not true. GeoLite or IP2Location LITE is free for use.

Comment: There is a commercial twist there in the bottom of the page : We also offer commercial redistribution licensing.