# Doing a location lookup based on IP Address and Subnet lookup table

Tags: python, excel, networking

I am a newbie to Python and looking for assistance how possible this is. I am looking for a way to do a lookup of IP Address that is in one file and do a lookup of where that IP Subnet is based on another file:

Device IP Address File:

Device  |   IP Address

--------    |   ------------

Server 1    |   1.1.1.1

Server 2    |   2.2.2.2

Server 3    |   3.3.3.3

Computer 1  |   4.4.4.4

Computer 2  |   5.5.5.5

Computer 3  |   6.6.6.6

Computer 4  |   7.7.7.7

Subnet File:

network |   cidr    |   type    |   Location

----------  |   ----    |   -----   |   -----------

1.1.1.0 |   /23 |   network |   Data Center - Zone 1

2.2.2.0 |   /23 |   network |   Data Center - Zone 2

3.3.3.0 |   /21 |   network |   Data Center - Zone 3

4.4.4.0 |   /21 |   network |   Office Location 1

5.5.5.0 |   /23 |   network |   Office Location 2

6.6.6.0 |   /28 |   network |   Office Location 3

7.7.7.0 |   /31 |   network |   Office Location 4

8.8.8.0 |   /31 |   network |   Office Location 5

What I am trying to do is get create a python script that will read Device IP Address from one file and do a lookup of location based on subnet of that IP Address that is listed in subnet file and output results to a new file:

Output File:

Device  |   IP Address  |   Location

--------    |   ------------    |   -----------

Server 1    |   1.1.1.1 |   Data Center - Zone 1

Server 2    |   2.2.2.2 |   Data Center - Zone 2

Server 3    |   3.3.3.3 |   Data Center - Zone 3

Computer 1  |   4.4.4.4 |   Office Location 1

Computer 2  |   5.5.5.5 |   Office Location 2

Computer 3  |   6.6.6.6 |   Office Location 3

Computer 4  |   7.7.7.7 |   Office Location 4

Currently these files are in XLSX format but can easily convert to another format if easier.

Comment: Already been asked I think [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163136/how-to-detect-the-country-and-city-of-a-user-accessing-your-site) You'll have to do some getting of IPs out of files into a structure but that should be easy with Python.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the desired file structure (in and out).

Comment: you can ignore the "|" in file format

Comment: This is not really what I was looking to do. I have the two files. I am trying to decipher location within my Internal network... I think the challenge with what I am looking to do is understand from my subnet file code needed to understand range of IP Addresses based on CIDR